# What does the "Attack Reaction" setting mean?

Tags: resident-evil-5

When choosing to continue your game, there are two settings it gives you: Co-Op Settings and Attack Reaction. The description for the Attack Reaction option is as follows:

> Partner [will/will not] react to your attacks.

What exactly does this means? By default it seems to be set to No, and the description seems a bit vague. Does that mean if I'm attacking an enemy, my partner will also attack that same enemy? Whatever it does, is there any benefit to using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changes how your partner reacts when you shoot them.

With **Attack Reaction: ON**, I remember that your partner would react to the shots as normal, they will hit your partner, your partner will shout\scream\bleed ect.

With **Attack Reaction: OFF**, Your partner will not react in any way if you shoot them. No blood, ect, and the bullet will pass right through them.

Regardless of which option you choose, you can never hurt your partner, it's visual effects only.

Comment: The bullet passes through them, as in will hit other targets behind them? That sounds like it could be beneficial when playing SP, as I've noticed the AI is a bit moronic in where it chooses to stand.

Comment: @animuson Very good question and I cannot remember at all. I would say YES out of memory but I'm not at all sure anymore, it has been quite some time.